# Bootstrap Collapse - Jquery "Collapse all" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a personal feed reader using Bootstrap on frontend, and wanted to add a "Collapse/Expand All" button.

It's my first JavaScript/JQuery code, so I don't know how to debug it except printing variables in Firefox Developer Console.

My page structure consist of panels. User can expand or collapse a panel by clicking on panel header. And a button to collapse or expand all panels.

My solution works most of the times, but I noticed one odd behavior. Here is how I reproduce the problem:

1. Open the page first time
2. Expand one panel with clicking its header
3. Now the collapse all button collapses the open panel, and expands the other ones. As if it "toggles" all panels instead of closing them.
4. After this odd behavior, everything is normal, I can't reproduce the problem without refreshing the page. On every step `open_panel_count` variable looks normal.

Here is the methods I'm using:

```js
$(function() {
  open_panel_count = 0;
  function update_toggle_button() { 
    $('#toggle-btn').text((open_panel_count ? "Collapse" : "Expand") + " All")
  }
  update_toggle_button(); // Run once on page load to text #toggle-btn

  $('#toggle-btn').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse(open_panel_count ? 'hide' : 'show');
  });

  $('.panel-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    open_panel_count++;
    update_toggle_button();
  });

  $('.panel-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    open_panel_count--;
    update_toggle_button();
  });
});
```

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

You can see the whole template in: https://github.com/utdemir/furby/blob/master/template.erb
And access a demo at: http://p.cogunluklazararsiz.org/furby/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Twitter Bootstrap documentation, you can "activate your content as a collapsible element.", by running:

```
$('.panel-collapse').collapse({
  toggle: false
});
```

Adding this should resolve your issue. Give it a go.

```
$(function() {
  $('.panel-collapse').collapse({
    toggle: false
  });

...
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Not sure why the twitter JS isn't picking up your `data-target="#entry419294611" data-toggle="collapse"`. Tough to debug without a fiddle.

Comment: If you are using Firefox, firebug add-on is a very popular debugging tool you might want to consider.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem, but I don't know why, I wasn't toggling it anywhere. Now looking to Firebug.

Answer (score 19):

```
$('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
```

[Bootstrap/JQuery Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#via-javascript)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chrome... JavaScript debugger says "collapse is not a function" :-/

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```
  $('#toggle-btn').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse(open_panel_count ? 'hide' : 'show');
  });
```

For

```
  $('#toggle-btn').click(function() {
    var state = open_panel_count ? 'hide' : 'show';
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse(state);
  });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't change anything. Am I wrong when thinking that expression would only evaluate once, and both codes are identical?

Comment: Looking into collapse code (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/collapse.js) It looks like runs an jquery.each then I think it is evaluate for each element with class panel-collapse