# Bootstrap Collapse Not Working with JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me insane.

I have this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="panel-head">


                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDiv" class="white-link" id="toggle" >Records Added
                    <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-left pad-right" id ="glyphicon"></span>
                </a>

            </div>


            <div id="collapseDiv" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
```

And I am trying to fire the collapse with this (in various ways):

`$('#collapseDiv').collapse("toggle")`

All I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function(…)

Any ideas?

```

```

Comment: jQuery should always be included fiirst.

Comment: change the sequence of the Jqueries you have included. 
first  JQuery.min.js or jQuery.js  then other.

Comment: can you please show us how you have added the javascript libraries on to your html page?

Comment: This might also happen if you're using jQuery.slim or a custom jQuery UI build from https://jqueryui.com/download/ which doesn't include effects.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure Jquery is included above Bootstrap, it works fine

```js
$('#collapseDiv').collapse("toggle");
```

```css
.white-link{color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="panel-head">


      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDiv" class="white-link" id="toggle">Records Added
                        <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-left pad-right" id ="glyphicon"></span>
                    </a>

    </div>


    <div id="collapseDiv" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
```

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem.... So in JQuery I did something like this:

```
$('#collapseDiv').removeClass('show');
```

As mentioned in [official doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/)...

1. .collapse hides content
2. .collapsing is applied during transitions
3. collapse.show shows content

so that is why I removed 'show' class and it worked for me... only drawback is that it hides immediately (without any animation)

Comment: I did the same, but I kept the animation by doing the following: $(this).slideUp('fast', function() {
                        $(this).removeClass('show');
                        $(this).attr('style', null);
                    });

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Lightbox (by Lokesh Dhakar) if I used:

```
<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but worked with:

```
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow, this was exactly my problem and the chances of having this specific problem are hilariously thin. nonetheless, appears these two libraries don't work well together. turns out if you put the full lightbox-plus-jquery script before query and bootstrap, things seem to work nicely...

Answer (score 1):

It took me an hour to figure it out.
Here is the simple solution. I will explain with three different method
1. Replace

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

with

```
declare var $ : any;
```

If it did't solve your problem than
2. make sure you import jquery and bootstrap in index.html as below, jQuery shoud be first

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">   
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If it did't work
3. than install jquery,jquery ui,jquery action and bootstrap

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Now import in your ts or js file

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Update angular.json file

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

That all it should work by now,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jquery 3.5.0 is giving error in using collapse feature of bootstrap 4 instead use jquery 3.4.1 version. it worked properly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="panel-head"> <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseDiv" class="white-link" id="toggle" >Records Added <span class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-left pad-right" id ="glyphicon"></span> </a> </div>
    <div id="collapseDiv" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">rywrujtwyjdtyjdsyjktyj</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check this. Your bootstrap.min.js/bootstrap.js is declare after your jquery library declaration.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using my jQuery code as a separate file in my Vue.js project. Even I imported jQuery in this file (which was installed using npm), I was continuously getting this 'collapse is not a function' error. I tried many solutions and was able to fix after this.

1. Install bootstrap using npm.
2. Import bootstrap after importing jQuery.

```js
import "bootstrap"
```

I hope this may be helpful for someone.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 $('.panel-collapse').collapse({
      toggle: false
    });
```

Source :[Bootstrap Collapse - Jquery "Collapse all" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015081/bootstrap-collapse-jquery-collapse-all-function)